# will a delay on a focusout allow me to click a link?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user search bar in the header. Upon typing, a div appears dynamically containing the relevant users. However when I go to click on the user's name, the focusout causes the div to immediately disappear thus the link is not clicked. How can I fix this issue?

Index.js.erb:

```
if($('#headersearch').val().trim() ==  "") 
  {
    $("#header_user_list").html('');      //empty search bar  => removes div
  }
else
  {
    $("#header_user_list").html('<%= j render @header_users %>')
  }
$('#headersearch').focusout(function() { $('#header_user_list').html(''); });
```

I do want to keep the focusout on the div when I click elsewhere. But I want to be able to click on the users' names to navigate to their pages. Is there a simple way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$('#headersearch').focusout(function () {
    $('#header_user_list').delay(30).hide(0, function () {
        $(this).empty();
    });
});
```

Or a classic timeout or a better logic.

Comment: I think hide causes the div to be removed for good. After i select and then deselect the search box, the div no longer appears when typing

Comment: it allows me to click the link but if I deselect the text box and try again the div doesnt even come up anymore

Comment: Ya because empty() will remove its children.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't get it wrong.. why don't you use a click function?
Something like:

```
$('yourElement').click(function() {
    // things that should happen after click, e.g.
    // opening a specific user page
    // or dismissing the menu
});
```